# What is Big O of two nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

I am trying to figure out Big O of following code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].someVariable; j++) {
    console.log("Hello world")
  }
}
```

`arr[i].someVariable` is any number from 1 to infinity.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing anything about `arr[i].someVariable`

Comment: it is any number, from 1 to infinity

Comment: Then Big O can be anything in between `array.length` (ie `n`) and `infinity`

Comment: I am not sure about that, hmmm

Comment: Well, what would you expect as answer, based on your description. The only thing that is for sure, is that the outer loop is executed `array.lenth` times. We don't know whether all of the `arr[i].somevalue` are constant or not, or if they depend on the length of the array or anything else. So there is no way of determining a sensible value for Big O

Comment: someVariable is constant value, it doesn't change, but it can be different for given index

Comment: Then it's O(n) ... Or you can also say it's O( n * m), where m is the maximum of someVariable. But as that is constant, it doesn't matter, thus it's again O(n)

Comment: Does the value of `arr[i].someVariable` increase as `i` increases?

Comment: @derpirscher: the quote "any number from 1 to infinity" leaves room for unbounded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity is `O(Σ Vi)` where `Vi` is `arr[i].someVariable` and the sum runs over all elements of `arr`.

A more intuitive expression is `O(N.V)` where `N` is the array size and `V` the average value of the `Vi`.

Comment: O(NV) = O(N) (if V does not depend on N).

Comment: @k314159: nothing being said about the distribution of the numbers, I prefer to leave V there.